# React Native builds work in simulators but not on ios device?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I have my build working fine on ios simulators, but when I plug in my iphone and run `react-native run-ios --device "Max’s Iphone 12 Mini"`, the build fails. Error Below from rn cli below.

The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/maxmandia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musicplace_ios-aaznfqkkkkeeldftonqjsqawrhgr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RCT-Folly/folly.framework/folly normal (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')

When I try to run the app in xcode, I get another error:

ld: -U and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together

Here is my pod file

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'musicplace_ios' do
  use_frameworks!
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'musicplace_iosTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Any help would be great! I tried disabling bitcode and it still showed ENABLE_BITCODE=YES in the error message - cleaned my build folder too. Really out of idea right now.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73014763/react-native-ios-xcode-build-failing-for-bitcode/73044513#73044513) which has been answered