# React native IOS Xcode build failing for bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am new to React Native. I am trying to build my app on my ios device. It is building fine in the emulator but whenever I try to do it on my ios device I am getting the following error (picture attached).

It used to build regularly on ios device. It stopped working after I installed firebase to it following the documentation,

https://rnfirebase.io/#3-ios-setup

[image]

Not sure but it might be a flipper issue with static libraries? But really struglling here on this for a few days. I even tried enabling and disabling the bitcode option in build setting and still the same error.

Comment: I’m getting the exact same error after installing firebase. Tried everything you have, including disabling flipper, and can’t get it working. Let me know if you are able to fix it.

Comment: Seems to be an issue when adding use_frameworks! to the podfile. App won’t run with firebase uninstalled but still having use_frameworks in podfile

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a problem with react native 0.69.1. The workaround ([as detailed here](https://github.com/mikehardy/rnfbdemo/issues/10)) is to disable bitcode in xcode settings:
[image]

Then add the following to post_install in your podfile:

```
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
end
```

It should look like this:
[image]

Make sure to comment out flipper as well

Finally run pod install in the iOS directory

Comment: I did all the recommended steps using RN 69.3 but it still fails with the error. Any ideas?

Comment: After upgraded all my modules it worked. I guess running "pod install" is a necessary step, so should be mentioned maybe in the resolution.